# Allow only text and multiple 0's before number, not [1-9]

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to match document numbers in an excel file to files in a folder.

Example file directories:

A) "C:\Users\directory\Supplier\Invoice1.pdf"

B) "C:\Users\directory\Supplier\Invoice001.pdf"

C) "C:\Users\directory\Supplier\Invoice101.pdf"

D) "C:\Users\directory\Supplier\Invoice10.pdf"

E) "C:\Users\directory\Supplier\Invoice21.pdf"

My regex pattern matches A, B and C but should only match A and B.

`Pattern = "(^|[^1-9])(DocNumber)([^0-9]|$)"`,
where DocNumber = 1 in my example (may also be any other number).

Any ideas on how I can improve my formula to not match C?

NOTE: I see other threads similar to this are unpopular, so I tried to make my problem clear as the others did not provide me with a solution.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your goal is but have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/aQXr3f/2/ (this will also return the number as a group).

Comment: Do you want to match the path as well as the filename or just the filename?

Comment: Try `"(?:^|\D)0*"&DocNumber&"\.[^.]*$"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this: `^.*[\\\/][^0-9]*0*1\..*$`

Example seen here: https://regex101.com/r/O7RdEq/4

Explanation:

- `^.*[\\\/]` - Match everything up to the last slash

  - `[\\\/]` - Match either a single backslash or a single forward slash; note that both slashes are escaped using a backslash.
- `[^0-9]*0*1\..*$` - Match every non-number up to and including any leading '0's, followed by your document number, and then the file extension

  - `[^0-9]*` - Match any non-numbers before the optional '0's; prevents cases like '101'
  - `0*1` - Optional '0's before the document number (1 in this case)
  - `\..*$` - Match a literal `.`, then any characters until the end of the line; should handle file extensions.

The `1` after the `0*` is the document number that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! Really nice answer, and not that complicated either. Now I just need to allow the Doc Number to be variable and my problem should be solved 100%. Apologies for the delay, I am in South Africa so there is a bit of time difference.

Comment: @R.Swanepoel `Pattern = "^.*[\\\/][^0-9]*0*" & DocNumber & "\..*$"` should do the trick.